# MySQL select join null values

Tags: mysql, join, null

Hi i'm trying on query that is going to show 4 values from each 4 tables.

```
select i.name, c.name, s.name, d.name
from instructor i
join course c
    on i.pid = c.instructor
join course_taken ct
    on c.id = ct.cid
join student s
    on s.id = ct.sid
join department d
    on s.major = d.id or s.major is null
where i.name = 'lee';
```

everything's fine except for the null part.

table structure

```
--------------------------------------------------
| student | course  | instructor | department    |
--------------------------------------------------
| name   | name     | id         | id            |
--------------------------------------------------
| id     | id       | name       | name          |
--------------------------------------------------
| major  |instructor| department |               |
--------------------------------------------------
```

the result

```
--------------------------------------------------
| i.name    | c.name  | s.name  | d.name         |
--------------------------------------------------
| kim       | math    | jack    | cs             |
--------------------------------------------------
| kim       | math    | john    | cs             |  --> THIS VALUE IS
--------------------------------------------------
| kim       | math    | john    | ss             |  --> NULL AND SHOULD BE PRINTED IN NULL
--------------------------------------------------
| kim       |math     | json    | ss             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**How do i print null if 'cs' and 'ss' in "john" is NULL?**

Answer (score 0):

USE `COALESCE()` function like

```
select coalesce(i.name,'NULL') as iName, ...
from instructor i
```

Per your comment looks like you don't want to have the `name` column output from `department` table at all. In that case just select `NULL` for it like

```
select i.name, c.name, s.name, null
```

(OR)

```
select i.name, c.name, s.name, 'null'
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that function. I'm trying to hide major (cs or ss if NULL). I tried `select i.name, c.name, s.name, coalesce(d.name, 'NULL')
from instructor i`, didn't work. still gets both 'cs' and 'ss' in major column :(

Comment: Oh sorry, i think i didn't realize about name i selected from above.. i edited the table that i need to output. I need major names, even if it is NULL. Like `cs / cs / ss / ss` into `cs / NULL / NULL / ss`. Thanks